# Acceder a ListView en ASCX desde el ASPX que lo usa

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net, listview, usercontrol

Tengo un proyecto (.NET 4) en el cual tengo unos WebMethods (en el **ASPX**) que están siendo consumidos desde un **ASCX**. La estructura sería la siguiente (los nombres me los invento, es para que veáis la jerarquía):

- Index.aspx => Aquí es donde necesito actualizar el ListView
- ControlAbuelo.ascx
- ControlPadre.ascx
- ControlObjetivo.ascx => Donde está el ListView.

El problema es que uno de esos WebMethods necesita actualizar el ListView localizado en **ControlObjetivo.ascx** ¿Como puedo acceder a ese ListView desde el **ASPX**?

He intentado poner los WebMethod en el **ASCX**, [pero no se puede](https://stackoverflow.com/a/579046/9657622)

PD: Se me olvidaba añadir que el proyecto está en VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución.

Puse un UpdatePanel como este:

```html
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upListDocumentos" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpdatePanel" EventName="Click" />
  </Triggers>
  <ContentTemplate>
  <%--... aqui iria el ListView--%>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

El button "btnUpdatePanel" lanza el refresco de la lista en el "onClick" y puedo forzar esa pulsacion desde JS con la funcion ".trigger("click")